# Unable to publish adapter using ant task on Worklight 6.2

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

My Deploy works nice from Eclipse, but whenever I try to run my ant script. I get the following error message.

[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /console/api/adapters/upload

I've included jars described bellow. The ant script I am using is:

```
<project basedir="." default="deploy">
<property name="worklight-ant-deployer" location="worklight-ant-deployer.jar" />
<target name="init">
<taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
<classpath>
<pathelement location="./lib/worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
</classpath>
</taskdef>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="init">

<adapter-deployer deployable="/pathTo/MyAdapter.adapter" worklightServerHost="http://localhost:10080/MyApp"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ant task is not up-to-date for Worklight 6.2. Review the following user documentation topic: [Updating deployment scripts](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_update_deployment_scripts.html)

The document details changes required to do in your script in order to get deploying via ant task working again.

More information on using Ant in Worklight 6.2 is available here: [Administering Worklight applications through ANT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/c_administering_ibm_worklight_applications_through_ant.html).

Comment: Looks like the ant libraries from Worklight 6.1 are incompatible with Worklight 6.2